# Angular5 deploy to Azure webapp: Content Security Policy

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, angular-cli

I want to deploy my angular5 app created with angular-cli to azure webapp service. What I did:

ng new testapp

ng build --prod --aot

cd dist

//dirty part for test case:

git init

git add *

git commit -m 'initial commit'

git remote add azure https://user@xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/xxx.git

git push azure master

output:

> Finished successfully. remote: Running post deployment command(s)...
>   remote: Deployment successful. remote: App container will begin
>   restart within 10 seconds.

so everything seems fine. If I head to the URL after deployment is done I unfortunately receive:

Cannot GET/

with the error:

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src http://xxx.azurewebsites.net”). Source: ;!function(){var t=0,e=function(t,e){ret.... xxx.azurewebsites.net:1

Every single tutorial or example I've seen so far did never bother with CSP or anything in that regard. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the CSP header as below,

```
<system.webServer>  
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="
        default-src 'self';
        style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        script-src 'self' https://*.vo.msecnd.net;
        connect-src wss: https:;" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

You may refer this document which will give you some information regarding CSP: https://www.henrihietala.fi/how-to-secure-your-asp-net-azure-web-app/.

Also, you can refer this MSDN thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/18425bf2-49d2-4ad6-824d-b84205ab0eea/adding-content-security-policy-xxss-protection-to-my-web-app?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview, might help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created a web.config in dist/ added it to the repo and pushed it. Nothing happened, still the same issue. Content of the file is this:


<system.webServer>  
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="
        default-src 'self';
        style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        script-src 'self' https://*.azurewebsites.net;
        connect-src wss: https:;" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>